# Typescript Playground Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'number[]'

Tags: typescript

[Playground can be found here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gRgDQwExYCz4C6AUHAHQCWYwANgK4AmAphABRoCUxQA)

```
const a = [1, 2, 4, 4]
a.includes(1)
```

I am using the latest settings in the playground with ESNext and typescript 3.8.3[image]

Comment: This may be an issue with Typescript Playground. I tried this in a react project and it worked. You have to define your "lib" in your `tsconfig.json` to `["dom", "esnext"]`

Comment: Fwiw i also have this issue on typescript playground but not locally. Might be worth logging a bug

Comment: I have exactly same issue. And where to log this bug? I couldn't find any links. Microsoft is so microsoft...